# Using inherited interfaces in interface implementations in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

How do I implement functions, which get inherited interfaces?
I have these interfaces:

```
interface IAnimal
interface IDog : IAnimal
interface ICat : IAnimal

interface IShelter
class DogShelter : IShelter
class CatShelter : IShelter
```

Now I want IShelter to have a function:

```
Store(IAnimal animal)
```

but I want DogShelter to implement it like this:

```
Store(IDog animal)
```

and CatShelter like this:

```
Store(ICat animal).
```

Is there a way to do this?
Apart from having DogShelter implement Store(IAnmial animal) and checking with "if(animal is IDog)"?

Should I go with Store(IAnimal animal) and then cast it with (IDog)animal?

(I'd like to use interface inheritance regarding IDog and ICat. Class inheritance is not possible in the real code)
(Computational time is kinda important at this point. Is it cheaper to use Store(IDog animal) instead of checking "if(animal is IDog)"? Or is it just a convenience?)

Comment: You might be better off with `IShelter<TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal { void Store(TAnimal); }`.

Comment: It matters a lot how you are going to use IShelter. Do you plan on having a collection of IShelter objects and then figuring out which IShelter some IAnimal goes to? If so, there's going to be a type check somewhere. The question is whether it happens inside the Store or not.

Comment: Certainly Jon Hanna's suggestion gets you the signature you want, but it can be difficult to work with multiple instances of a generic interface that differ only in the type parameter from the caller's perspective.

Comment: I've accepted the generics answer. It works as intended (i.e. reducing complexity of my structures), at least in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution. You should use [generics constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

```
        interface IShelter<T> where T : IAnimal
    {
        void Store(T animal);
    }
    class DogShelter : IShelter<IDog>
    {
        public void Store(IDog animal)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class CatShelter : IShelter<ICat>
    {
        public void Store(ICat animal)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Though a fine answer, you sort of re-wrote the definition of `IShelter` by making it a generic.  OP may want to just have methods elsewhere in the app that take a plain old `IShelter` and not a `IShelter<T>`.  (see Mike z's comments below question)

Comment: Like each solution in software development, my solution has a drawback. The plain old IShelter can not be reused. Runtime checking may be an option but should not be preferred. The compiler does not help when it is not done correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution. Although Micky's objection is right, it is not an issue in the project I'm working on.

Comment: Good to hear that it won't be a problem Rian. +1 Daan